# How to write a query for one to many mapped records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got these three tables.

- channels (id, id_account, kind, datetime, state, id_target)
- channel_contacts (id, id_channel, id_contact, archived)
- channel_events (id, id_channel_contacts, code, details, datetime)

channel_contacts relationship to channels

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `CONTRAINT` (`id_channel`, `id_contact`),
INDEX `idx_channel_contact_archived` (`archived`),
INDEX `channel_contacts_ibfk_2` (`id_contact`),
CONSTRAINT `channel_contacts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_channel`) REFERENCES `channels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `channel_contacts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_contact`) REFERENCES `contact` (`id_contact`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

channel_events relationship to channel_contacts

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `id_channel_contacts` (`id_channel_contacts`),
CONSTRAINT `channel_events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_channel_contacts`) REFERENCES `channel_contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

As one can see they are related.

I want all those events from channels_events table which belong to id_account 123 in channels table.

I have written the following query which gives me the following problem of

> Unknown column 'channel_contacts.id_channel' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT channels.id, channels.kind, channels.publish_date,
  channel_contacts.id_channel, channel_contacts.id_contact,
  channel_contacts.archived, channel_events.id,
  channel_events.id_channel_contacts, channel_events.code,
  channel_events.details, channel_events.occation
FROM channel_events
JOIN channels
  ON channels.id = channel_contacts.id_channel
JOIN channel_contacts
  ON channel_contacts.id_contact = channel_events.id_channel_contacts
where channels.id_account = 123;
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please update the question with proper tag. And please explain what does it means  `is not working`?

Comment: I am sorry i have updated my title and description trying to make it more explanatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a typo ,You've placed the join with channels table before channels contacts, so channels_contanct isn't recognized yet. Try this:

```
SELECT channels.id, channels.kind, channels.publish_date, channel_contacts.id_channel, channel_contacts.id_contact, channel_contacts.archived, channel_events.id, channel_events.id_channel_contacts, channel_events.code, channel_events.details, channel_events.occation
FROM channel_events 
JOIN channel_contacts ON channel_contacts.id= channel_events.id_channel_contacts
JOIN channels ON channels.id = channel_contacts.id_channel
where channels.id_account = 123;
```

Comment: The query doesn't give me any error but it doesn't return any result as well even though there are records in the tables.

Comment: Becuase you didn't post your relations, and probably made another typo here: channel_contacts.id_channel= channel_events.id_channel_contacts .

Comment: I think this is the wrong relation, I've updated the question and changed it, try it now @Shaonline

Comment: I think it is the right outer join. When i user right outer join i get all the records and details is null which shouldn't be.

Comment: No, you need an inner join! please provide the foreign keys and primary keys in each table @Shaonline

Comment: there are primary keys and foreign keys in each table. I still couldn't find what the problem is

Comment: @Shaonline Please listen, the query is perfectly fine, the only thing that is not good is the JOIN conditions(the ON(... = ...)) . This is because you didn't specify which column relate to which column

Comment: So please post the relations between them.. channels_contact.id_channel = channels.id? ... ETC

Comment: I added it in the description above. Please have a look, Thank you.

Comment: I added the relationship of channel_contacts and channel_events above, While channels is related to user table by id_account referring to id_user of user table.

Comment: Great. Now it works :) thanks a lot. So it was supposed to be channels_contacts.id and not channels_contacts.id_contact.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem :) @Shaonline